# INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY or UPDATE... SET

Tags: php, mysql

I have a INSERT..  ON DUPLICATE KEY  which just will not update, instead inserts a new row. I have a  2 unique keys but still it is just inserting new rows.
I have tried unique keys on multiple rows to see if that was the problem, but still getting the same issue.

So i was wondering would using UPDATE table SET ... be more suitable or should i stick with INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE.

I have a products table, which i want my administrators to be able to change/update whenever they like. At the moment i have a INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE but it is giving me endless problems.

I have a unique key on both the primary key(i know it is not needed, for test purposes only) and the restaurant name, as logically i thought if having a unique key on the restaurant name alone is not working. Maybe by making both the restaurant id and restaurant name a unique key the function would update row and not insert a new one. But still not working, this is my last resort as i cannot figure out the issue.

**UPDATE**

A new row is only inserted if i change the restaurant name, if i change anything else the table updates.

```
  if (isset($_POST['Save-dets'])) {
        $r_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Resturant_ID']);
        $r_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['rest_name']);
        $r_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Desc']);

  $insert_rest = "INSERT INTO Rest_Details
  ( Resturant_ID
  , Resturant_name
  , Resturant_des) 
  VALUES
  ( ?
  , ?
  , ?
  ) 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE Resturant_ID = ?
  , Resturant_name               = ?
  , Resturant_des        = ?";

         $run_query = $dbc->prepare($insert_rest);
       $run_query->bind_param($c, 'ssssss', $r_id, $r_name, $r_desc,$r_id, $r_name, $r_desc );


        if (!$run_query->execute($run_query))


        if ($execute) {
            echo "<script> alert('Addrrss Saved')</script>";

    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    }
    }

CREATE TABLE `Rest_Details` (
`Resturant_ID` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Resturant_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Resturant_des` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Resturant_ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Resturant_ID` (`Resturant_ID`,`Resturant_name`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=243 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Your opinion on this matter would be very helpful.

Comment: What is the value of `$r_id`?

Comment: @JonStirling the restaurant id. On this particular restaurant  3

Comment: Okay, does it make a difference if you change your bind param line to use `ississ` instead of `ssssss`? And you should remove `Resturant_ID = ?` as it's redundant.

Comment: And can you / have you confirmed with a var_dump that `$r_id` is definitely 3?

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` when you're using parametrized queries.

Comment: When it inserts a new row, what's in the `Restaurant_ID` column? Is it really creating rows with duplicate IDs?

Comment: @JonStirling it has stopped inserted new rows which is a plus. it says a row has been effected, but i can't find the row which has :S. I will continue to change it and see what happens

Comment: @Barmar It creates a new rid, but the name and description of the restaurant get changed to what i changed it too

Comment: @JonStirling and yes i have. I tried it on 3/4 restaurants and the the rest_id is returned

Comment: @JonStirling I have just checked it is still inserting new rows

Answer (score 0):

Please check your usage at

```
$run_query->bind_param($c, 'ssssss', $r_id, $r_name, $r_desc,$r_id, $r_name, $r_desc );
```

You are mixing object-oriented style parameters with functional style parameters - see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Based on the at documentation it would either be

```
$run_query->bind_param('ssssss', $r_id, $r_name, $r_desc,$r_id, $r_name, $r_desc );
```

or

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($c, 'ssssss', $r_id, $r_name, $r_desc,$r_id, $r_name, $r_desc );
```

Comment: You got there just before i did, i have literally just changed this before seeing your answer. Have now realised that everything else changes fine, but if i try and change the restaurant name thats when i knew row is inserted